# A measure of redundancy in mutual information

Tags: descriptive-statistics, information-theory, mutual-information

Mutual information quantifies to what degree $X$ decreases the uncertainty about $Y$. However, to my understanding, it does not quantify "in how many ways" $X$ decreases the uncertainty. E.g., consider the case where $X$ is a 3D vector, and consider $X_1=[Y,0,0]$ vs. $X_2 = [Y,Y^2, 3.5Y]$. Intuitively, $X_2$ contains "more information" about $Y$, or is more redundant with respect to $Y$, than $X_1$; but if I understand correctly, both have the same mutual information. Is there an alternative information-theoretic measure that can quantify this difference?

Thanks!

Comment: worth to read: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.05063.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Comparative study of Mutual Information measures

- A comparative study of standard Shannon entropy along with variations of Coding Theorem Method(CTM) and Block Decomposition Model(BTM) as shown in [A Decomposition Method for Global Evaluation of
  Shannon Entropy and Local Estimations of
  Algorithmic Complexity](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.00110.pdf)
- General guide for [Estimating mutual information](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/8463957_Estimating_Mutual_Information) and its applications in gene expression data and independent component analysis.

### Information-theoretic Python Packages

## `dit`

This python package for discrete information theory provides a standard bivariate case based on

1. Basic Shannon measure of [mutual information for bivariate distributions](https://dit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/measures/shannon.html#mutual-information)
2. Measures for multivariate distributions

   - [Co-Information](https://dit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/measures/multivariate/coinformation.html): quantifies amount of information all variable participates in
   - [Total Correlation](https://dit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/measures/multivariate/total_correlation.html): amount of information each individual variable carries above and beyond joint entropy
   - [Dual Total Correlation](https://dit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/measures/multivariate/dual_total_correlation.html): Also known as binding information is the amount of information shared among the variables.
   - [Cohesion](https://dit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/measures/multivariate/cohesion.html): spans total correlation to dual total correlation
   - [CAEKL Mutual Information](https://dit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/measures/multivariate/caekl_mutual_information.html):

   > Generalized as the smallest quantity that can be subtracted from the joint, and from each part of a partition of all the variables, such that the joint entropy minus this quantity is equal to the sum of each partition entropy minus this quantity.

   - [Interaction Information](https://dit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/measures/multivariate/interaction_information.html): Equal in magnitude to co-information, however for odd number of variables takes the opposite sign
   - [DeWeese-like Measures](https://dit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/measures/multivariate/deweese.html)

   > local modification of a single variable can not increase the amount of correlation or dependence it has with the other variables.

## `pyitlib`

Library in python for [information-theoretic methods](https://pypi.org/project/pyitlib/).

Below are the mutual information measures found in `pyitlib` package

- [Mutual information](https://pafoster.github.io/pyitlib/#discrete_random_variable.information_mutual)
- [Normalised mutual information (7 variants)](https://pafoster.github.io/pyitlib/#discrete_random_variable.information_mutual_normalised)
- [Variation of information](https://pafoster.github.io/pyitlib/#discrete_random_variable.information_variation)
- [Lautum information](https://pafoster.github.io/pyitlib/#discrete_random_variable.information_lautum)
- [Conditional mutual information](https://pafoster.github.io/pyitlib/#discrete_random_variable.information_mutual_conditional)
- [Co-information](https://pafoster.github.io/pyitlib/#discrete_random_variable.information_co)
- [Interaction information](https://pafoster.github.io/pyitlib/#discrete_random_variable.information_interaction)
- [Multi-information](https://pafoster.github.io/pyitlib/#discrete_random_variable.information_multi)
- [Binding information](https://pafoster.github.io/pyitlib/#discrete_random_variable.information_binding)
- [Residual entropy](https://pafoster.github.io/pyitlib/#discrete_random_variable.entropy_residual)
- [Exogenous local information](https://pafoster.github.io/pyitlib/#discrete_random_variable.information_exogenous_local)
- [Enigmatic information](https://pafoster.github.io/pyitlib/#discrete_random_variable.information_enigmatic)

### Other measures in Research Communities

Apart from this, there are few best approaches as I have found in the research communities which looks promising to quantify measures of redundancy

1. **Part mutual information**: This new measure is based on information theory that accurately quantify nonlinearly direct associations between measured variables. For more information, [part mutual information for quantifying direct associations](https://www.pnas.org/content/113/18/5130)
2. **Calculate mutual information using recursive adaptive partitioning**: This paper ideally focuses on [mutual information between discrete variables with many categories using Recursive Adaptive Partitioning](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep10981)
3. **Comparative redundancy calculations**: A comparative study of existing redundancy calculations with new measure of bivariate redundancy measure. [A Bivariate Measure of Redundant Information](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.2080.pdf)
4. **Synergistic mutual information**: briefly explains about how single PI-region is either redundant, unique or synergistic. Research paper:   [Quantifying synergistic mutual information](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.4265.pdf)
5. **Partial Information Decomposition**: a redundancy measure as proposed by Williams and Beer which typically introduce partial information atoms(PI-atoms) to decompose multivariate mutual information into non-negative terms. Refer to [Nonnegative Decomposition of Multivariate Information](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.2515.pdf)
6. **Absolute mutual information**: This measure is calculated using algorithmic complexity
7. [**Pairwise adjusted mutual information**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.12641.pdf)
8. **partial correlation**: However it can only measure linear direct associations
9. **Conditional mutual information** quantify nonlinear direct relationships among variables, ideally for more than 2 variables

Answer (score 1):

One way to quantify computational redundancy is with [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity). Kolmogorov complexity is how complex a computer program is required to create an object.

There are [conditional versions of Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Conditional_versions)  that could be applied to your problem. It will take more computation resources to specify $X_1$ relative to $X_2$ if both were given $Y$ as a prior.